# stopped unexpectedly in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-emulator

can someone help me? I would like to display a map in the screen of my android but when I try to run my emulator, I got the error: "unexpectedly stopped, please try again". 
I use eclipse .
Here are my log:

```
10-03 12:20:48.578: W/dalvikvm(1643): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/formation/gmaps/MainActivity; (976)
10-03 12:20:48.578: W/dalvikvm(1643): Link of class 'Lcom/formation/gmaps/MainActivity;' failed
10-03 12:20:48.597: D/AndroidRuntime(1643): Shutting down VM
10-03 12:20:48.597: W/dalvikvm(1643): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.formation.gmaps/com.formation.gmaps.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.formation.gmaps.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.formation.gmaps-1.apk
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.formation.gmaps.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.formation.gmaps-1.apk
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
10-03 12:20:48.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1643):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you list the steps you have done before getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Check Your Logs it Says this,

```
Didn't find class "com.formation.gmaps.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.formation.gmaps-1.apk
```

> So please check your package com.formation.gmaps ,does it contains
>   this MainaActivity and check your manifests also to confirm that

Answer (score 0):

Try it in your device instead of emulator sometimes it works fine with device.

Answer (score 0):

Like the log says, there was an error of linking the MainActivity, so some code from there might be useful

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for yours answers!
yes! my package com.formation.gmaps contains this MainActivity and here is my androidManifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.formation.gmaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My MainActivity:

```
    package com.formation.gmaps;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapActivity;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapView mapView = new MapView(this);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMapFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/map.map");
        setContentView(mapView);
    }
}
```

So should I get a new package or?